# Trying to put JSON file into JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a JSON file containing:

```
[{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com"
}]
```

I am now trying to add these into a JS array, and try to show them as an alert on my mobile:

```
$.getJSON('links.json', function (json) {
    var linkList = [];
    $.each(json, function(i, obj) {
        linkList.push([obj.title, obj.url]);
    });
});

$.each( linkList, function( key, value ) {
  alert( value.title + ": " + value.url );
});
```

But when I run it on my phone no alerts are shown. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`$.each(JSONObject.results.bindings, function(i, obj) {`

to

`$.each(json, function(i, obj) {`

Edit: Also, you should be declaring `var linkList = []` outside the scope of the `$.getJSON` function (above it). Otherwise it will be undefined in the global scope.

Edit 2: Oh, even more importantly, $.getJSON is an asynchronous function. What's happening is you're starting to load the .json file, and then your code continues on to the alert part. At this point, it hasn't been loaded yet, so the array is always empty. Then a few milliseconds later, it loads the JSON, it's just too late. Move your `$.each` code inside the `$.getJSON` callback.

Comment: Now something happend (After your second edit). Now I get the 3 alerts, but all of them says "undefined : undefined".

Comment: Remove the `.value` from `obj.title` and `obj.url`.

Comment: In that case, add this line above `linkList.push`:
`console.log(obj);`. Then check your console, it will verify what `$.getJSON` is producing.

Comment: Oh whoa never mind, I should've reviewed your code more closely. You're converting the data into an array in your push. Instead, just change your push line to `linkList.push(obj);`. (Or, you can change the alert line to `value[0]` and `value[1]`.)